# How to replace value `null` in JSON string to `NaN` or `NaT`?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
inp= [{'c1null':10,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3time':null}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1null':11,'cols':{'c2':null,'c3time':'2014-05-24 19:20'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1null':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3time':'2016-06-24 19:20'},'c4':'43'}]
df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(inp)
print(df)
```

There's value `null` in `inp` JSON string,then above script cannot successful json_normalize to get expect result as below:

```
c1null   c4      cols.c2           cols.c3time
0    10  41       20                  NaT
1    11  42       NaN             2014-05-24 19:20
2    12  43       20              2016-06-24 19:20
```

Now, I use `pd.read_sql` to get the dataframe, need to replace value `null` to `NaN` or `NaT` when key named `*time`,then we can use `pd.io.json.json_normalize`.

How to replace value `null` in dataframe JSON string column to `NaN` or `NaT`?

Comment: @DYZ,actually it's `null` in mysql.I use `pandas.read_sql` to read mysql table to dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
from numpy import nan as null
inp= [{'c1':10,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3time':null}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1':11,'cols':{'c2':null,'c3time':'2014-05-24 19:20'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3time':'2016-06-24 19:20'},'c4':'43'}]
df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(inp)
df
Out[494]: 
   c1  c4  cols.c2       cols.c3time
0  10  41     20.0               NaN
1  11  42      NaN  2014-05-24 19:20
2  12  43     20.0  2016-06-24 19:20
```

---

```
df['cols.c3time']=pd.to_datetime(df['cols.c3time'])
df
Out[497]: 
   c1  c4  cols.c2         cols.c3time
0  10  41     20.0                 NaT
1  11  42      NaN 2014-05-24 19:20:00
2  12  43     20.0 2016-06-24 19:20:00
```

Comment: In pandas, should be `NaT` in `cols.c3time`?

Comment: @kittygirl here you need change the column types also see the update

Comment: If I only have dataframe `df`,can I use your method after `df.to_dict('records')`?Actually I have only dataframe come from `pandas.read_sql`.

Comment: @kittygirl sorry get confused maybe adding `from numpy import nan ; from pandas import NaT`